# How these two lines work x2 = x+delta[i][0] , y2 = y+delta[i][1]?

Tags: python, algorithm, artificial-intelligence, depth-first-search

I'm reading the code below about First Search Program - Artificial Intelligence for Robotics and I stuck a little with the work of these two lines below:

```
x2 = x+delta[i][0]
y2 = y+delta[i][1]
```

I know about delta for the movement pattern from a node to the neighbors, but I couldn't understand how these two lines are working here. Could anyone explain them for me please?.

The code below:

```
#grid format
# 0 = navigable space
# 1 = occupied space

grid=[[0,0,1,0,0,0],
      [0,0,1,0,0,0],
      [0,0,0,0,1,0],
      [0,0,1,1,1,0],
      [0,0,0,0,1,0]]

init = [0,0]                           
goal = [len(grid)-1,len(grid[0])-1]   

#Below the four potential actions to the single field
delta=[[-1, 0],      #up 
       [ 0,-1],      #left
       [ 1, 0],      #down
       [ 0, 1]]      #right

delta_name = ['^','<','V','>']        
cost = 1

def search():
    #open list elements are of the type [g,x,y] 

    closed = [[0 for row in range(len(grid[0]))] for col in range(len(grid))]
    #We initialize the starting location as checked
    closed[init[0]][init[1]] = 1

    # we assigned the cordinates and g value
    x = init[0]
    y = init[1]
    g = 0
    #our open list will contain our initial value
    open = [[g,x,y]]


    found = False #flag that is set when search complete
    resign= False #Flag set if we can't find expand

    #print('initial open list:')
    #for i in range(len(open)):
            #print('  ', open[i])
    #print('----')


    while found is False and resign is False:
        #Check if we still have elements in the open list
        if len(open)==0: #If our open list is empty
            resign=True
            print('Fail')
            print('############# Search terminated without success')
        else: 
            #if there is still elements on our list
            #remove node from list
            open.sort()      
            open.reverse()    #reverse the list
            next = open.pop() 

            #print('list item')
            #print('next')

            #Then we assign the three values to x,y and g. 
            x = next[1]
            y = next[2]
            g = next[0]

            #Check if we are done

            if x == goal[0] and y == goal[1]:
                found = True
                print(next) #The three elements above this if
                print('############## Search is success')
            else:
                #expand winning element and add to new open list
                for i in range(len(delta)): 

                    x2 = x+delta[i][0]
                    y2 = y+delta[i][1]
                    #if x2 and y2 falls into the grid
                    if x2 >= 0 and x2 < len(grid) and y2 >=0 and y2 <= len(grid[0])-1:
                        #if x2 and y2 not checked yet and there is not obstacles
                        if closed[x2][y2] == 0 and grid[x2][y2] == 0:
                            g2 = g+cost #we increment the cose
                            open.append([g2,x2,y2])#we add them to our open list
                            #print('append list item')
                            #print([g2,x2,y2])
                            #Then we check them to never expand again
                            closed[x2][y2] = 1

search()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`x2` and `y2` are the position after the i'th potential action in delta is performed.

`delta[i][0]` means the first element of the i'th action in delta (the change in x caused by the i'th action)

`delta[i][1]` means the second element of the i'th action in delta (the change in y caused by the i'th action)

So `x2=x+delta[i][0]` and `y2=y+delta[i][1]` are applying that i'th potential action and storing the resulting new x and y values in `x2` and `y2`.

In the context of this program, these values are created for each potential action (`for i in range(len(delta))` and if the resulting position falls into the grid, hasn't been checked yet, and doesn't have obstacles, then the position is added to the `open` list.

Comment: @ Bhaskar. Thank you so much Sir for your explanation. After your permission, I didn't get the (+) sign between (x and delta) and (y and delta). What they mean here exactly, by this summation?.

Comment: The (+) sign is adding the change in x caused by the action (delta[i][0]) to the original position x. That x plus the change in x gives you the resulting new x caused by that specific action. E.g. if you're using delta[2] which is [1, 0], then x2 would be x + 1 and y2 would be y + 0, effectively shifting (x, y) one unit to the right.